# Back in Intent again, app performing slow

Tags: android, bitmap, fragment, lifecycle

In my app, I have two intent. In first intent, i take image as input from gallery and camera. Then i send the uri to the next activity. Where i convert the uri into bitmap and apply some effect on bitmap. The activity contains two fragment. I do filtering inside asynctask. App performs well for first time. But when i am back to my first activity and move to next, then it performs slowly.

In MainActivity, I have used this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EditorPage.class);
intent.putExtra("imageUri", cropUri.toString());
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

In EditorActivity, I have used this code for back button

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
finish();
```

Before coming in EditorActivity i am using a third party library for cropping image. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Back button doesn't need an intent, just call `super.onBackPressed`

Comment: when i use `super.onBackPressed ` it exit my app to system tray

Answer (score 0):

Cropping the image is a good start. 
But I think the loaded bitmap might still be slowing down your app performance.

I suggest you use `Glide` to load your bitmap. 
Glide is `An image loading and caching library for Android focused on smooth scrolling`
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Thanks for you advice, i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try don't close your `MainActivity` as follow

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EditorPage.class);
intent.putExtra("imageUri", cropUri.toString());
startActivity(intent);
//finish(); <--- remove this line
```

And just call `onBackPressed()` withou call `startActivity()` as follow

```
//remove this bellow line
//startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
finish();
```

Comment: `@Override public void onBackPressed() { finish(); }` will i use like that

Comment: You can use as `@Override public void onBackPressed() { super.onBackPressed(); } `

Comment: still getting same result

Answer (score 0):

If your activity hierarchy is `First` -> `Second` then opening `Second` from first should not call `finish()` or `onBackPressed()`.

Navigate `First` -> `Second`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EditorPage.class);
intent.putExtra("imageUri", cropUri.toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

And to go back from `Second` to `First` call `finish()`, provided that `Second` was started by `First` and not by some other way. Make sure you release all resources from `Second` before calling `finish()`

---

If `Second` is not always started by `First`, you need to take some extra steps:

1. Add `First` as parent of `Second` in manifest

   ```
   <activity
       android:name="...Second"
       android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
       android:parentActivityName="...First"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
       <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
           android:value="...First" />
   </activity>
   ```
2. Call a function something like this:

   ```
   public final void navigateUp() {
       Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
       if (upIntent == null) {
           onBackPressed();
       } if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent) || isTaskRoot()) {
           TaskStackBuilder.create(this).addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent).startActivities();
       } else {
           upIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
           NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: 2nd is always running with 1st activity. Here i have tried same approach as you say. I think i am not releasing all resource. Here i am releasing bitmap only. But 2nd activity contains two fragment also. Do you think, i need to destroy them also??

Comment: No, they are managed by activity. You should learn how to use systrace and figure out method what is taking all the time

Comment: after removing asynctask, using handler with runnable, communucating by bundle message, i am getting better result. But it is 90% ok. not 100%.